# lcc printf floating point

Tags: c, floating-point, windows-xp

I have following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int args, char *argv[]) {
    printf("%f\n", 0.99999);
    printf("%e\n", 0.99999);
}
```

The result is:

```
0.009990
9.999900e-001
```

Why is the first number wrong?  I use Windows XP, compiler "Logiciels Informatique lcc-win32 version 3.8. Compilation date: Nov 30 2012 19:38:03".

Comment: Are you using [lcc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCC_(compiler)) or its derivative [lcc-win](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~lcc-win32/)? Do you have the same problem if you add #include <stdio.h>? (It's not just a precision problem; the output is off by a factor of 100.)

Comment: When I use printf("%e\n", 0.99999); The answer is correct 9.999900e-001

The problem occurs only for specific numbers.

Comment: I use lcc-win, and yes the <stdio.h> is included.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but what if you try `printf("%f\n", 0.99999f);` ??

Comment: That information needs to be in your question. Please update it to mention that you're using lcc-win (and which version), and update the source code to the version that actually has the `#include <stdio.h>` (and still exhibits the problem). Be sure you copy-and-paste the entire program.

Comment: It's the ghost of the [Pentium FDIV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_FDIV_bug). IWO a `printf()` bug.

Comment: You might want to contact the [lcc-win](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~lcc-win32/) maintainer directly.

Comment: @KeithThompson: A user with reputation 1 showing a genuine compiler bug should have some sort of award.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Too late; his reputation is now up to 16. 8-)}

Comment: At the very least there should be a badge for “new user asks first question about FP and it isn’t a dupe”.

Answer (score 2):

That program is correct, and its output should be:

```
0.999990
9.999900e-01
```

or something *very* similar to that.

(You don't use `args` or `argv`, and the usual name for the first parameter of `main` is `argc` rather than `args`, but neither of those is a problem that should affect your program's behavior.)

It looks like you've found a bug in your implementation, probably in the runtime library rather than in the compiler itself. My brief Google searches haven't turned up a reference to this particular bug (in fact, the top hit was this question).

I suggest contacting the maintainer of lcc-win; contact information is on the [web site](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~lcc-win32/). A short description and a link to this question should provide enough information, at least to start.